# Is there any way to specify "not" in iTunes search?

Tags: itunes, search

Whenever I want to listen to songs from a particular band in iTunes, I'll just type the name in the search box, select shuffle, and start playing. For most bands this works very well, but I've run into a few situations where I'm unable to narrow it down to a single band due to the fact that the name of the band I'm looking for is a subset of the name of a different band. A classic example is "The Who" - every time I type "the who" in my search bar I get "The Guess Who" as well.

I've tried some of the basic tricks like using quotes or minus symbols but nothing seems to work. Is there a way to do this, or do I have to create special playlists for these problem bands?

Comment: o_O iTunes is version TEN and still doesn't contain a NOT operator?! Staggering.

Comment: @torbengb Surprisingly iTunes doesn’t use Spotlight we all know, at least directly. You can disable finding music in Spotlight and iTunes will still find your music; the reason behind this is probably because Windows doesn’t have Spotlight. But they could have added *some* syntax…

Answer (score 3):

iTunes doesn’t seem to exhibit any sort of *smart* searching built into the search box. Possibly, the best way to deal with these things is to use an external tool.

In my case, I have [Coversutra](http://www.sophiestication.com/coversutra/) (not free), that allows you to press “tab” (can be changed) to select different things:

[image]

I know there are *free* alternatives that can possibly do the same thing.

An additional alternative could be using an AppleScript and Automator to “ask” for the values… but that might be too much.

```
tell application "iTunes"
  activate
  set results to (every file track of playlist "Library" whose name contains “some track" and artist contains “some artist")
  repeat with t in results
    play t
  end repeat
end tell
```

Something like that, if you can make automator (or the script) to ask you for the two “some” values, you’re set.

*My opinion*: iTunes should support spotlight like search strings!

**UPDATE** Ok, you’re right about that one, Coversutra (and others) all use iTunes “syntax” which is… no syntax.

Spotlight, however, is a different beast.

In trying to replicate your scenario, I’ve found that I have two “artists” that are similar in name: *Metallica* and *Metalium*. They both contain “Meta” in their names.

So when I search for artist “meta” I get both, which is annoying, because I really don’t like Metalium that much…

So I have two solutions for you:

a. Use Launchbar (or quicksilver), to quickly find the artist (this is a nice way to do it and what I really use most of the time when I want to find a song or an artist, it works faster than anything else). I use Launchbar. Pressing enter there creates a temporary playlist (called Launchbar) that contains all the tracks in question, but you could have dig a little bit more if you wanted an album or song. Very easy.

[image]

b. Use Spotlight:

This brings both bands:

```
kind:mp3 author:meta
```

[image]

but this excludes the unwanted one:

```
kind:mp3 author:meta NOT author:metalium
```

[image]

Not the best but… what can we do :)

Comment: I tried CoverSutra but it suffers from the same search problem iTunes does.

Comment: @Kyle if you can get used to LaunchBar, your way of launching apps, and working with your computer are going to change; for better :) I haven’t tried Alfred (http://www.alfredapp.com/) yet, but it looks promising (and it has a free version with less features). QuickSilver I dropped a couple of years ago when its original author said: “I’m not developing this anymore” (later someone else did …)

Answer (score 2):

I'm not aware of any way to do that type of boolean searching in iTunes (and neither is [this](http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=367058) poster),  I use smart playlists to do this (sorry if you're already aware of these, just fyi).

[image]

Comment: given the problematic on this issue, that's a very elegant solution!